# Bug -- "Vot" and "Answe"

Tags: bug, status-completed

On my questions page, whenever a question has but a single upvote, the following is displayed:

[image]

Zooming out has nothing to do with it: if I zoom out a lot, I just get very teeny-tiny "answe"s and "vot"s, and if I zoom in, they just get big.

Comment: I can easily see how this would happen on the system side. :)

Comment: And a link so people can confirm: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/31475/arkamis?tab=questions

Comment: **Clearly** your monitor has ran out of ink.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I had a similar problem with my car. It ran out of blinker fluid. I've paid the mechanic three times to fix it, but I guess it has a leak.

Comment: It's not a bug. The website was never really rendered. There is a sweatshop in Indonesia where thousands of little kids type out the code for the output of each request. You just ran into one that had typos. Don't worry, he got fired. From a cannon. Into the sun.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Such a shame. He might not have been accurate, but he was precise.

Comment: Answe is just a cute way of saying Answer :)

Comment: Oh lovely, did someone call the "strip ending for singular function" twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in build rev 2013.7.30.1289 (meta) / 2013.7.30.902 (sites).